# How can I restore a Firefox profile with my saved passwords from a Windows backup?

Tags: firefox

I installed Windows 7 and forgot to do something about saving my Firefox settings except for a full backup through Windows Backup. I also copied all my files in my home directory to an external drive, not fully trusting Windows Backup to get everything I needed. So I essentially have 2 ways of getting back my old files.

Now I would like to get my profile from the previous installation to work in the freshly installed Windows 7 system. Can this be done if I have the previous files under AppData?

What do I do to restore the profile?

I also happen to have all of the old files in C:\Windows.old if I need them.

Btw, I did try copying the old profile files back in place (see location below) but it just did not work.

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles

Comment: I found the proper profile location and was able to restore my profile!

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/profiles#How_to_find_your_profile

Comment: Since you answered your own question - which is totally cool - copy your comment into the answer and mark it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the proper profile location and was able to restore my profile! http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/profiles#How_to_find_your_profile

Answer (score 0):

I think, now you have restored your lost profile, you can try [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.org/) to not doing that the next time:

> MozBackup is a simple utility for creating backups of Mozilla Firefox, Mozilla Thunderbird, Mozilla Suite and Netscape profiles. It allows you to backup and restore bookmarks, mail, contacts, history, extensions, cache etc.